# "subject" parameter in "externalObjectDrop" function is empty

Tags: gojs

e.subject parameter in the "externalObjectDrop" function comes with count=0,
although the dragged parts are moved to the model.

in the diagram:

```
  allowCopy: true,
  allowUndo: false,
  allowInsert: true,
  allowDragOut: true,
  allowDrop: true,
  allowMove: true,
  "ExternalObjectsDropped": (e) => {
                this.externalObjectDrop(e);
            }
```

the function:

```
  externalObjectDrop(e) {
 e.diagram.commandHandler.deleteSelection();
 e.parameter.commandHandler.deleteSelection();
   //e.subject.count is 0.
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that behavior with the code that you have given.  When I try it, it works as expected:         $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            allowCopy: true,
            allowUndo: false,
            allowInsert: true,
            allowDragOut: true,
            allowDrop: true,
            allowMove: true,
            "ExternalObjectsDropped": (e) => {
              var coll = e.subject;
              console.log("total dropped: " + coll.count);
              coll.each(function(part) { console.log("  " + part.key); });
            }
          })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.subject contains a reference, not value. so, after calling:  `e.parameter.commandHandler.deleteSelection()`
 - e.subject becomes empty.
so I save e.subject to parameter, and then delete selection:

```
const nodes = e.subject.toArray();
 e.parameter.commandHandler.deleteSelection();
```